# NUnit Unit Test Fails as it expects not null, how can this be mocked with moq to not get this

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, teamcity, moq

I am getting the following error message in a Web API controller Testing project which is using NUnit.  In the Web Test Unit test, i'm not using Moq, but I would like to use it as currently the real services are getting invoked.   TeamCity is what is reporting this error

**Error from TeamCity on the NUnit test**

```
(new) Portal.WebAPI.Tests.dll:        
Portal.WebAPI.Tests.Controllers.CalendarEventControllerTest.CalendarEventController_SearchCalendarEvent_Success

Test(s) failed.   Expected: not null
But was:  null

at NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(Object actual, IResolveConstraint expression, String message, Object[] args)
at NUnit.Framework.Assert.IsNotNull(Object anObject)
at Portal.WebAPI.Tests.Controllers.CalendarEventControllerTest.   

<CalendarEventController_SearchCalendarEvent_Success>d__1e.MoveNext() in h:\BuildAgent\work\8d99e8b3faa82424\NxtGen\Portal.WebAPI.Tests\Controllers\CalendarEventControllerTest.cs:line 107
at NUnit.Framework.AsyncInvocationRegion.AsyncTaskInvocationRegion.WaitForPendingOperationsToComplete(Object invocationResult)
```

at NUnit.Core.NUnitAsyncTestMethod.RunTestMethod()

**Code**

```
[Test]
public async Task CalendarEventController_SearchCalendarEvent_Success()
{
    CalendarEventController controller = new CalendarEventController();
    CalendarEventSearchRequest request = new CalendarEventSearchRequest();
    request.ClientId = 123;
    CalendarEventSearchResponse response = await controller.SearchCalendarEvents(request);

    Assert.IsNotNull(response.data);
}
```

I gather that the issue is `Assert.IsNotNull(response.data);`   as it is not null, thus teamcity runs and the nunit test fails, right?

Problem is that I don't know what valid "clientid" even are.   Really shouldn't this just my mocked/faked anyway?  How can I use Moq in this situation?

Comment: "as it is not null" - well no, the problem is that it *is* null, but you're expecting that it *isn't* null. It's not clear how Moq comes in, given that the code you've shown doesn't use Moq at all. It's also not clear where TeamCity is relevant here - does the test pass locally but fail in TeamCity? (If it fails locally, why are you even getting as far as TeamCity running it?)

Comment: I believe you want to use Moq to mock the CalendarEventController, correct? But this would really defeat the purpose of the unit test since (guessing from the naming of the test method) you are testing the SearchCalendarEvents operation. You will need to setup the test correctly so that it can work.

Comment: Ok,   yes I need to figure out how to get it to pass.